# Another supplier is already registered with the key: DefaultChildStack while using Decompose and Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, koin, compose-multiplatform

## What is expected

on process death and orientation change, the component instance be retained and state preserved

## What I've tried

In a compose multiplatform project shared directory

```kotlin
class DefaultRootComponent(componentContext: ComponentContext) : RootComponent,
    ComponentContext by componentContext, KoinComponent {

    ...

    override val childStack: Value<ChildStack<*, RootComponent.Child>>
        get() = childStack(
            source = navigation,
            initialConfiguration = Config.HomeScreen,
            handleBackButton = true,
            childFactory = ::createChild
        )
    ...
}
```

in MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalDecomposeApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        val root = retainedComponent { componentContext ->
            DefaultRootComponent(componentContext)
        }

        setContent {
            val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
            val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

            DisposableEffect(systemUiController, useDarkIcons) {
                systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
                    color = Color.Transparent, darkIcons = useDarkIcons
                )

                onDispose { }
            }

            MainView(
                root = root,
                useDarkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
                dynamicColor = true,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Koin logs just before the crash

```bash
|- 'ui.homescreen.HomeScreenComponent' ...
| >> parameters DefinitionParameters[com.arkivanov.decompose.DefaultComponentContext@164207, (kotlin.String) -> kotlin.Unit] 
| << parameters
|- 'ui.homescreen.HomeScreenComponent' in 20.7406 ms
```

android runtime crash logs

```bash
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ayitinya.hostelogo, PID: 6134
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another supplier is already registered with the key: DefaultChildStack
at com.arkivanov.essenty.statekeeper.DefaultStateKeeperDispatcher.register(DefaultStateKeeperDispatcher.kt:44)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.router.children.ChildrenFactoryKt.children(ChildrenFactory.kt:93)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.router.children.ChildrenFactoryKt.children$default(ChildrenFactory.kt:61)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.router.stack.ChildStackFactoryKt.childStack(ChildStackFactory.kt:91)
at com.arkivanov.decompose.router.stack.ChildStackFactoryKt.childStack(ChildStackFactory.kt:40)
at navigation.DefaultRootComponent.getChildStack(DefaultRootComponent.kt:106)
...
```

Comment: I think the issue is because your childStack property has a getter, so it registers a new instance of ChildStack on every access. You should just assign ChildStack to the property.

Comment: Works like a charm. Would be grateful if you good give a quick explainer on how that changes things.

thanks a lot @ArkadiiIvanov

Comment: Sure! The `childStack` function is an extension function on `ComponentContext`. When called, it attaches the Child Stack to the `ComponentContext`. Calling the method multiple times with the same `key` argument (or with the default key if not specified) throws an error, because another Child Stack already exists.

Comment: that's understood, thank you @ArkadiiIvanov